# Concatenate strings in Terraform for tags with condition

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I am trying to give my EC2 instances tags as below

```
resource "aws_instance" "EC2" {

  count = var.instance_count
  key_name               = var.key_name
  ami                    = var.ami
  instance_type          = var.instance_type
  vpc_security_group_ids  = [var.security_group_id]
  subnet_id              = split(",", var.subnet_id)[count.index]
  disable_api_termination = var.disable_api_termination
  instance_initiated_shutdown_behavior = var.instance_initiated_shutdown_behavior
   tags = {
     Name = var.instance_count != 1 ? "var.server_name-${count.index}" : var.server_name
   
  }
  
}
```

We want to merge the server_name and count.index. If the server_name is smtp and instance_count is 1 then output should be smtp, or if instance_count is 2 then it should be smtp1 & smtp2

```
tags{
Name = var.instance_count !=1 ? "var.server_name-${count.index + 1}" : var.server_name
}
```

Output (for instance_count = 1):

```
Name = -
```

Please help.

Comment: What is the actual value of `var.server_name`?

Comment: It's 'smtp' for now. We can modify it to something else

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only issue I see is that it should be (missing `${var.server_name}`):

```
var.instance_count !=1 ? "${var.server_name}-${count.index + 1}" : var.server_name
```